# Serve both HTTP and WS clients

Tags: java, http, websocket, server

Is it possible to implement a Java based server both HTTP requests and listening to websockets? I would like to response JSON objects to HTTP clients and customer objects to websocket clients.

Comment: Every Java EE server supports this. So it's really hard to understand why exactly you're asking this question with the [java-ee] tag present on the question. Such a question implies that you actually never tried/used a Java EE server at all and only wanted to homegrow ( :X ) a "server". For this reason, I've stripped off the [java-ee] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is possible. A web server will anyway respond to HTTP requests given that you have implemented [servlet/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) that match the paths clients are requesting. You can use a servlet container to host your servlets. When you say Sockets([not web sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)) I assume that you're talking about opening a port where Java server will be listening to any UDP or TCP based requests that may be coming through internal network or from other network. You can find many source code samples for implementing a UDP or TCP server that listens on a given port.

Also note that opening multiple ports on the server opens up a security threat if port is visible to outside network.

Comment: Do you mean two separate programs should run in the server (the physical server computer) ?  one is servlet on say tomcat and the other is socket server on jvm ?

Comment: No. You can run both on the same JVM. When you have a working Java web application, you can just add another class that will also be listening on a given port for incoming requests